# Renew an expiring server TLS cert when the client has the server cert embedded?

Tags: ssl-certificate, ca

*(This is for a new project, so I'm still considering options.)*

I've got a server and client (phone app) communicating via gRPC, and now I'm looking into securing that connection. A common recommendation I see is to just use a self-signed server key, and embed the server's certificate directly within the client. This lets the app trust the server without requiring a cert download or third party CAs.

However, my understanding is that these certificates are only good for a year (per the openssl command to generate them). Wouldn't there be a problem in trying to renew the cert, when the old version is directly embedded in the client? I don't see how you could prepare the client for the new cert either, as both server and client would have to use the same cert for every request, right?

Given how often I see this method suggested, how do you get around the expiration problem?

Comment: If you want to just get around the expiration problem, one option is to generate cert for longer validity which can be specified using "-days <no_of_days>" option while generating certificate using openssl command line.
e.g. for 10 years validity: openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 3650

Comment: Another option from security perspective is instead of hardcoding the certificate, let both client as well as server to read the certificate from some path, and update the cert file in the path every year (or as needed).

Comment: Given that the client is a phone app, a shared path would have to be something like a public URL. Is there any risk there, or is a certificate basically public knowledge anyway?

Comment: If the purpose is just encryption, client certificate is optional for a successful SSL connection. Client certificate is needed only if you need to authenticate client also. Your use case (phone app) seems similar to how browsing https sites work, where client (browser) generally doesn't have any certificate. It just verifies the server certificate, even that is also optional if server is already trusted. See https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tg-multi/9.2?topic=ssl-how-connection-is-established.